# How to write back to a PDB file after doing Superimposer for atoms of a protein in PDB.BIO python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I read and extracted information of atoms from a PDB file and did a `Superimposer()` to align a mutation to wild-type. How can I write the aligned values of atoms back to PDB file? I tried to use `PDBIO()` library but it doesn't work since it doesn't accept a list as an input. Anyone has an idea how to do it?

```
mutantAtoms = []
mutantStructure = PDBParser().get_structure("name",pdbFile)
mutantChain = mutStructure[0]["B"]

# Extract information of atoms
for residues in mutantChain:
  mutantAtoms.append(residues)

# Do alignment 
si =Superimposer()
si.set_atoms(wildtypeAtoms, mutantAtoms)
si.apply(mutantAtoms)
```

Now `mutantAtoms` is the aligned atom to wild-type atom. I need to write this information to a PDB file. My question is how to convert from list of aligned atoms to a structure and use `PDBIO()` or some other ways to write to a PDB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in an example in the `PDBIO` [package documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/_api_161/Bio.PDB.PDBIO'.PDBIO-class.html) in `Biopython` documentation:

```
p = PDBParser()
s = p.get_structure("1fat", "1fat.pdb")
io = PDBIO()
io.set_structure(s)
io.save("out.pdb")
```

Seems like `PDBIO` module needs an object of class `Structure` to work, which is in principle what I understand `Superimposer` works with. When you say it does not accept a list do you mean you have a list of structures? In that case you could simply do it by iterating throught the structures as in:

```
for s in my_results_list:
    io.set_structure(s)
    io.save("out.pdb")
```

If what you have is a list of atoms, I guess you could create a `Structure` object with that and then pass it to `PDBIO`.

However, it is difficult to tell more without knowing more about your problem. You could put on your question the code lines where you get the problem.

**Edit**: Now I have better understood what you want to do. So I have seen in an interesting [Biopython Structural Bioinformatics FAQ](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ#The_Structure_object) some information about the `Structure` class, which is a little complex apparently. At first sight, I do not see a very easy way to create `Structure` objects from scratch, but what you could do is modify the structure you get from `PDBIO` substituting the atoms list with the result you get from `Superimposer` and then write the `.pdb` file using the same modified structure. So you could try to put your `mutantAtoms` list into the `mutantStructure` object you already have.

Comment: Hi cnluzon, I updated my question. I have a list of aligned atoms and I have no idea how to create a Structure object as you told to pass it to PDBIO. If I want to create a Structure object, I need to call get_structure API from a PDB file but I don't have any PDB file to call (except for the original one). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have extended my answer with some extra information. I hope it's of some help.